# flutter ImageAsset Image extending outside BoxDecoration container

Tags: image, flutter

I have Image inside a BoxDecoration that works when I get the image from CachedNetworkImageProvider but when I get the image from Assetimage the image is not clipped to the box size. Both image sources are displayed in ListTile.
Code from AssetImage:

```
      return Container(
      width: widget.width, 
      height: widget.heigth,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      border: Border.all(color:widget.colour, width:3),
      image: DecorationImage(
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      image: AssetImage(url)
       )....
```

Code from CachedNetworkImageProvider:

```
return Container(
width: widget.width, 
height: widget.heigth,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  shape: BoxShape.circle,
  border: Border.all(color:widget.colour, width:3),
  image: DecorationImage(
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(widget.location.imageURLs[widget.index])...
```

[image]

Comment: I can not reproduce. Perhaps there is something wrong with `image.width`/`image.height`

Answer (score 1):

use the following sample

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(

                image: DecorationImage(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  matchTextDirection: true,
                  repeat: ImageRepeat.noRepeat,
                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/bed.jpg"),
                ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having it as a property of boxDecoration.image, have you tried setting it to child?

```
return Container(
child: DecorationImage(
fit: BoxFit.cover,
image: AssetImage(url)
)....
width: widget.width,
height: widget.heigth,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
shape: BoxShape.circle,
border: Border.all(color:widget.colour, width:3)),
```

Comment: I get a compile error saying  that you can't assign DecorationImage to type widget

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Okay, here I quickly made this lazy method

```
   Container(
              width: 70,
              height: 70,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: AppColor.appColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                    height: 70,
                    width: 70,
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                        image: new DecorationImage(
                          image: new NetworkImage(
                            'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296387-5358ad7997bb?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8cG9ydHJhaXRzfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80',
                          ),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ))),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
  image: AssetImage(url).image
```